# Proof that the eccentricity of a planet in orbit is always greater than or equal to zero

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, geometry, celestial-mechanics

I was looking into the formal proof of Kepler's laws of planetary motion and I happened to come upon this equation for the eccentricity of the orbit:

$$e=\sqrt{\frac{2EL^{2}}{G^{2}M^{2}m^{3}}+1}$$

For the proof of Kepler's first law I was studying, it seems necessary to prove that e is always $\ge0$ in order to solve this integral:
$$\theta=-\int_{ }^{ }\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{e^{2}}{r_{0}^{2}}-\left(u-\frac{1}{r_{0}}\right)^{2}}}du $$
Where $u=1/r$ and $r_0 = \frac{L^2}{GMm^2}$.

Since $e$ is always $\ge0$, $\frac{2EL^{2}}{G^{2}M^{2}m^{3}}+1$ must also be $\ge0$. I have tried to prove this by substituting $$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2\ }-\frac{GMm}{r}$$ as well as $$E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2 + \frac{1}{2}mr^2\dot{\theta}^2-\frac{GMm}{r}$$ but so far I've been unable to prove it. Could anybody help me or at least point me in the general direction?

Comment: What would an ellipse with [negative eccentricity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2138638/295847) look like?

Comment: When I plugged it into the equation in Desmos, it looked pretty much the exact same with $-1<e<0$ being an ellipse, $e=-1$ being a parabola and $e<-1$ showing a hyperbola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start with the energy

$$E=\frac m2 \vec v\cdot \vec v-\frac{G\,m\,M}{|\vec R|} $$

with:

$$\vec R=r(\varphi)\,\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\varphi) \\
   \sin(\varphi) \\
 \end{bmatrix}
~,\quad 
r(\varphi)=\frac{p}{1+e\cos(\varphi)}~,p=\frac{h^2}{G\,M}$$

$$\vec v=\frac{\partial\vec R}{\partial\varphi}\,\dot\varphi~,
\quad \dot{\varphi}=\frac{h}{R^2}~,
\quad h=\frac{L}{m}$$

Thus the energy is:

$$E=\frac 12\,{\frac { \left( {e}^{2}-1 \right) {M}^{2}{m}^{3}{G}^{2}}{{L}^{2}}
}
$$

solving this equation for $e^2$ you obtain

$$\boxed{e^2=\frac{2\,E\,L^2}{m^3\,M^2\,G^2}+1}$$

---

How you obtain $~r(\varphi)$
\begin{align*}
  &\text{start again with the energy }\\
  &E=\frac{m}{2} \left( {{\dot{r}}}^{2}+{r}^{2}{\dot\varphi }^{2} \right) +U \left(
r \right)\\
&\text{with}\\
&\dot{\varphi}=\frac{h}{r^2}\qquad,\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{d\varphi}\dot{\varphi}\\
&E=\,m{h}^{2} \left( {\frac {{{\left( \frac{dr}{d\varphi}\right)}}^{2}}{{r}^{4}}}+\frac{1}{r^2}
 \right) +U \left( r \right)\\
 &\text{solving this equation for $~\frac{d\varphi}{dr}~$ and with } ~ h^2=\frac{L^2}{m^2} \\
 &\frac{d\varphi}{dr}=\frac{1}{r^2}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,{\frac {m \left( E-U \left( r \right)
 \right) }{{L}^{2}}}-\frac{1}{r^2}}}}\\
 &\text{the potential energy  $~U(r)=-\frac{G\,m\,M}{r}~$ and for eliptical  path $~E=0~$ you obtain}\\
  &\frac{d\varphi}{dr}=\frac{1}{r^2}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,{\frac {G\,M{m}^{2}}{r{L}^{2}}}-\frac{1}{r^2}}}}\\
  &\Rightarrow\\
  &\varphi=2\,\arctan \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2\,G\,M{m}^{2}r-{L}^{2}}}{L}} \right)\\
  &\text{or}\\
  &r={\frac {{L}^{2}}{G\,M{m}^{2} \left( \cos \left( \varphi  \right) +1
 \right) }}\\
 &\boxed{r(\varphi)=\frac{p}{1+\cos(\varphi)}}
 \end{align*}

Comment: Very nice explanation. I have voted up all :-)

Comment: Doesn't this proof require you to already know r as a function of angle? I wanted to prove that $e\ge0$ so that I could then solve the integral and find r in terms of angle.

Comment: @ShudheshVelusamy if e > 1 then the energy E > 0 you obtain hyperbolic path, e < 1 elliptic path e=1 parabolic path

Comment: @ShudheshVelusamy I put more information how to obtain elliptical path

Comment: @Eli Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Eccentricity,_focus_and_directrix), $e$ is a ratio of two lengths. Since these are $\ge0$, so is $e$. Meanwhile, $$1+\frac{2EL^2}{G^2M^2m^2}=1+\frac{2Er_0}{GM}$$ is $\ge0 \iff E\ge-\frac{GM}{2r_0}$, which is true for closed orbits by the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem).

Comment: Is true also for open orbits as $E>0$

Answer (score 0):

A more trivial proof is by using the [eccentricity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector) (which is a vector with the same direction as the semi-major axis and whose modulus equals the eccentricity of the conic)

$$\mathbf{e}\equiv\frac{\mathbf{A}}{mk}=\frac{1}{mk}(\mathbf{p}\times \mathbf{L})-\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$
$$|\mathbf{e}|\equiv\frac{|\mathbf{A}|}{mk}\geq0$$

---

~*References*

- [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector)
- [Eccentricity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector)